# Junit test on this method without using assert?

Tags: java, junit

```
@Requires("d >= 0") //pre-condition
@Ensures("data == d") //post-condition
public Natural(int d) {
    data = d;
}
```

how can i test "data == d" on JUnit without using assert?

Comment: Is that `assert` as in the keyword, or `Assert` as in the static class?

Comment: assert as in the keyword

Comment: What's the purpose of having a method like that?

Comment: i have to write pre and post condition on natural method then do junit test on it but Junit test must be done without using "assert"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not rely on `assert` statements for your tests, as this can be disabled.

You should instead look through the [`Assert`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/org/junit/Assert.html) class in JUnit, which has a number of methods for testing results.

In your case, I presume you have either access to `data`, or can determine a side effect of `data`, which can be tested.